# Insert into Object Type and return from Stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I've a Table Employee

```
EMPID                  EMPNAME                                                                                             
---------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1                      prabhu                                                                                               
2                      b                                                                                                    
3                      c
```

I want to write stored procedure which will send output parameter as OBJECT.

My Select query inside proc is

```
SELECT EMPID, EMPNAME FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

This will have multiple rows and hence I want to pass this resultset as object

Now I 've created type as,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMP IS OBJECT
    (EMPNO NUMBER,EMPNAME VARCHAR2(100));
```

PROC:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TYPEOUT(EOUT OUT EMP) AS

<code>

BEGIN

<CODE>
END TYPEOUT;
```

PLEASE help me out to complete the proc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return multiple rows you need an object which supports multiple instances.  That is a collection type, such as a nested table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMP_NT AS TABLE OF EMP;
```

We populate nested tables with a BULK operation.  So your procedure will look something like  this (note the change of argument datatype):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TYPEOUT(EOUT OUT EMP_NT) 
AS
BEGIN
    select emp(empid, empname)
    bulk collect into eout
    from employee;
END TYPEOUT;
```

Read the PL/SQL reference to [find out more about collections](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS005).   Also, the procedure would benefit [from exception handling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS007).

Comment: I'm getting Error(2,25): PLS-00329: schema-level type has illegal reference to LIVERW.EMP error

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that your table name was actually EMPLOYEE.  I have corrected my code: please try it again.

Comment: Many Thanks.It was due to Type name inccorect. It wass my mistake. Please can you help me how to print the values of eout?